# sending Html in json request for contactus page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

HTML:

```
     <form id="myemailform" role="form"  name="myemailform" ng-submit="sendMail();">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Your Name"ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" required ng-minlength ="1" />                      
    <input type="email" class="form-control"maxlength="40" name="email" id="email" ng-model="email"placeholder="Your Email" required />                      
    <input type="text" class="form-control sub" name="mobilenumber" ng-model="mobile"id="mobilenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control sub" name="subject" ng-model="subject"id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />  
 <textarea class="form-control sub" name="message" rows="5" cols="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" ng-model="message" placeholder="Message"  required ng-minlength ="1"></textarea>
 <input type="submit"  class="btn applyBtn" name="submit"/>
   </form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sendMail = function(){
    $scope.newMessage = "<p>Name:"+$scope.name+"</p>"+"<p>MobileNo:" + $scope.mobile+"</p>"+"<p>Query:" + $scope.message+"</p>" ;
            console.log($scope.newMessage);
                var json = {
              "request": {
                  "name":$scope.name,
                 "from":$scope.email, 
                  "to": "sunitha_anilkumar@yahoo.com",
                  "subject": $scope.subject,
                  "message": $scope.newMessage
              }
            }

UserService.contactus(json).then(function (res) {
            if(res.json.response.statuscode == 0){
}
});
}
```

I need to send my request to backend as html format , so that user will recieve the message submitted with formatted html . But when mail comes , I am just getting the content as

mobile no : 782671

query: my query

need solution.

Comment: Is you getting correct json on server ??

Comment: yes . But in mail , I am getting the html tag only

Comment: What is the output of `console.log` ??

Comment: that is <p> mobile no : 1123455 </p> <p> Query: new message </P>

Comment: what are the values of `$scope.name` and `$scope.message` ??

Comment: $scope.name="myname"; $scope.message="mymessage";

Comment: you shared only client side code examples why the problem is probably on server side

Comment: is it like , server need to convert it ?